# Can I achieve a scrollable flex container without a scrollbar on mobile devices using css only?

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox

I uploaded a video here : https://streamable.com/uyddy

I am asking if I can somehow hide the horizontal scrollbar in that specific div, while still being able to scroll? I want to achieve this on mobile devices.

I attached the code here : 
https://codepen.io/UrsuGrizzly/full/aVRZyg/
https://jsfiddle.net/o2ucuorL/

```
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="#" id="all">All</a>
  <a href="#">Images</a>
  <a href="#">Videos</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Maps</a>
  <a id="books" href="#">Books</a>
  <a id="flights" href="#">Flights</a>
  <a id="personal" href="#">Personal</a>
  <a id="stools" href="#">Search tools</a>
  <a id="moar" href="#">More</a>
  <a href="#" id="settings">Settings</a>
  <a href="#" id="tools">Tools</a
</div>

body{
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
 }

 #bottom{
  grid-area: 2/1/3/3;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x:scroll;
 }

 #bottom a{
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
  padding: 14px 16px 12px 16px;
  }

 #bottom #stools{
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  padding: 14px 16px 12px 24px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }

 #bottom #all{
  color: #4285f4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4285f4;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I'd do is just to wrap the #bottom div inside a parent div with a fixed height and the overflow property set to hidden. Then you just have to give the #bottom div a padding-bottom with the same height as the scrollbar has (like 10px more or less). And thats all :), works great. Leave here the code:

```
// HTML Part
<div class="container">
 <div id="bottom">              
  <a href="#" id="all">All</a>
  <a href="#">Images</a>
  <a href="#">Videos</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Maps</a>
  <a id="books" href="#">Books</a>
  <a id="flights" href="#">Flights</a>
  <a id="personal" href="#">Personal</a>
  <a id="stools" href="#">Search tools</a>
  <a id="moar" href="#">More</a>
  <a href="#" id="settings">Settings</a>
  <a href="#" id="tools">Tools</a>
 </div>
</div>

// CSS Part
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    }

.container {
    height: 43px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#bottom {
    grid-area: 2/1/3/3;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

#bottom a {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000008a;
    padding: 14px 16px 12px 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

#bottom a#all {
    color: #4285f4;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4285f4;
}
```